# download images just while scrolling items in a QML listView or gridview

Tags: qt, listview, qml

any idea for doing it? Imagine we have a long listview and we're going to just download image of items that are visible.(i.e. items that are visible on screen)

Answer (score 0):

Delegates in a views are [created as needed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#details); that is, as they come into view. However, the `visible` property is true by default, so to check whether an item is actually visible, you could make use of [currentIndex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#currentIndex-prop) and [contentY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentY-prop):

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 600
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: 200
        height: 200
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: 50
        onContentYChanged: currentIndex = contentY / height

        delegate: Image {
            width: listView.width
            height: width
            source: "http://www.blah.com/image" + index + ".png"
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            ListView.onIsCurrentItemChanged: {
                if (ListView.isCurrentItem) {
                    print("Downloading image at index " + index + "...");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that the delegates are square, and are the same size as the view itself; although, using this approach, all that really matters is the height of the view and delegates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mitch. it's great but actually i'm going to download images too. I do something like this: 'Component.onCompleted: {
                if (!fileExists("data/"+imgPath)){
                    downloadImg(imgPath)
                }
            }' it works correctly too but i like just download 'visible items' and not in 'onComplete' signal.(I use cacheBuffer too for smooth scrolling) is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Mitch. your code is okay but unfortunately changing "currentIndex" of Listview every time, less the smoothness of scrolling behaviour.I use this code in my delegate for now and it's not bad, perhaps i write a better approach later:

```
property bool isVisible : ((y > GridView.view.contentY) && y < (GridView.view.contentY + GridView.view.height))

onIsVisibleChanged: {
    if (isVisible && !exists("data/"+ImgPath)){
        print("Downloading image at index " + index + "...")
        isVisible = false
    }
}
```